# Need help in converting this jQuery code snippet to normal javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()){
        $('nav').addClass('black');
    }
    else {
        $('nav').removeClass('black');
   }
})
```

I tried using an online converter but that also didn't work.

Comment: Can you show us how far you have got and exactly what you are stuck on?

Comment: Have you tried searching for: "on scroll in vanilla javascript" "window.scrollTop in javascaript" "addClass in javascript" "removeClass in javascript" [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  

const nav = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0]
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  const top = window.pageYOffset
  if (top) {
    nav.classList.add("black")
  } else {
    nav.classList.remove("black")
  }
})
```

```css
.black{
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--head tag starts here-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>Salam</nav>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

  </body>
</html>
```